# multilevel advanced xml Parsing , tried many solutions works only 1 level

Tags: xml, parsing, nested

I have a multi-level XML file that needs to parse with python, I have xml or lxml. How do I parse? I could not find any useful solution.Please help me, thanks a lot! Ideally, I want to parse the XML file and convert to Python DataFrame. This for loop does not work.
the link for Json  or xml data

https://directory.spineservices.nhs.uk/ORD/2-0-0/organisations/REN?_format=xml
https://directory.spineservices.nhs.uk/ORD/2-0-0/organisations/REN?_format=json

tried with XMl
with xml script the output
import xml.etree.ElementTree
import os,requests
url1= requests.get(r'https://directory.spineservices.nhs.uk/ORD/2-0-0/organisations/REN?_format=xml')
xmldata= url1.content
print (xmldata)

xml string is enclosed with b'<xml_string>' in output  so could not proceed further

couldnt get too far , please  help with this

used Json after trying Xml
tried with json -----------------------------------

```
    import os,requests,json ,urllib.request
    import pandas as pd
    #from flatten_json import flatten
    #url=r"https://directory.spineservices.nhs.uk/ORD/2-0-0/organisations/REN"
    url1= requests.get(r"https://directory.spineservices.nhs.uk/ORD/2-0-0/organisations/REN")
    #data1= pd.read_json(url) 
    data=url1.json()
    data2=pd.DataFrame(data).T
    data2</sub>
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and add a short, representative sample of your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Following using Power Shell script will create a CSV file using the xml URI

```
using assembly System.Xml.Linq

$uri = 'https://directory.spineservices.nhs.uk/ORD/2-0-0/organisations/REN?_format=xml'
$outputFilename = 'c:\temp\test.csv'

$doc = [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Load($uri)
$rels = $doc.Descendants('Rel')

$table =  [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()
foreach($rel in $rels)
{
   $id = $rel.Attribute('id').Value
   $relId = $rel.Attribute('uniqueRelId').Value
   $startDate = $rel.Descendants('Start')[0].Value
   $endDate = $rel.Descendants('End')[0].Value
   $startDate = $rel.Descendants('Start')[0].Value
   $status = $rel.Element('Status').Attribute('value').Value

   $orgid = $rel.Descendants('OrgId')[0]
   $root = $orgid.Attribute('root').Value
   $authName = $orgid.Attribute('assigningAuthorityName').Value
   $ext = $orgid.Attribute('extension').Value

   $primary = $rel.Descendants('PrimaryRoleId')[0]
   $primaryId = $primary.Attribute('id').Value
   $roleId = $primary.Attribute('uniqueRoleId').Value

   $newRow = [pscustomobject]@{ID=$id;RELID=$relId;ROOT=$root;'AUTH NAME'=$authName;EXTENSION=$ext;'Primary Role ID'=$primaryId;'Unique Primary Role ID'=$roleId;}
   $table.Add($newRow)
}
$table | Format-List
$table | Export-CSV -Path $outputFilename -NoTypeInformation
```